# React - can not remove row from table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following table in React:

```
<div>
            <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>List Names</th>
                    <th>List Full Names</th>
                    <th>List Descriptions</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>{this.displayTableBody()}</tbody>
            </table>

            <button style={{display:'inline-block'}} type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-small"
            onClick={this.addList}>
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
            </button>

            <button style={{display:'inline-block'}} type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-small"
                    onClick={this.removeList}>
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
```

The `displayTableBody` method shows the body of the table:

```
displayTableBody: function() {
    var rows = Array.apply(null, Array(this.state.rowNr)).map(
        function(e1, index) {
            return <ListInput key={index} ref={index}/>
        }
    );
    return { rows };
}
```

Where `ListInput` represents a row of the table:

```
return (
    <tr>
        <td>{this.displaySimpleInputField(
            "List Name(<15 characters - A-Z, 0-9 and _ only)", this.setListName, "input")}</td>
        <td>{this.displaySimpleInputField(
            "List Full Name(<75 characters)", this.setListFullName, "input")}</td>
        <td>{this.displaySimpleInputField(
            "List Description(<225 characters)", this.setListDescription, "input")}</td>
    </tr>
)
```

The table has a button to add and one to remove rows.
When clicking the button to remove a row, this method gets called:

```
removeList: function() {
    this.setState({rowNr: this.state.rowNr - 1});
},
```

I am able to add rows.
However, when I try to remove rows I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: receiveComponent(...): Can only update a mounted component.
```

Comment: May I suggest to reposition your remove button aligned to the each row itself and then each row has id as your reference..

and then filter out your array ! == to the index  of your map function. just like this one .https://github.com/srph/playground/tree/master/react/todo

Comment: Are you somehow calling `removeList` before the component is mounted in some code we're not seeing here?

Comment: I am not calling `removeList` anywhere else.

Comment: Can you show us your componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount functions please? I had the same error recently which was caused by me not removing a change listener in componentWillUnmount.